# Flickity 2 - groupCells and pageDots not working at the same time

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, flickity

I am new to [flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) and I want to group cells and display dots at the same time.
But on my project they seems to be mutually exclusive, I can either group cells or display dots, even if from this [codepen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/XKZXyv), they do work well together.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

mypage:

this html is part of the template in my angularjs custom directive:

```
app.directive('productSlider', function ($rootScope, $compile, $timeout, $sce, $location, $window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<section id="products" >' +
            '<div class="prodotti-int gallery js-flickity" id="productSlider" data-flickity=\'{ "groupCells": 4 }\' >' +
            ... +
```

here is my jquery inside the **link** method of my directive:

```
$('#productSlider.gallery').flickity({
                            // options
                            cellAlign: 'center',
                            freeScroll: true,
                            wrapAround: false,
                            contain: true,
                            autoPlay: 0,
                            prevNextButtons: false,
                            pageDots: false
                        });
```

In this case, the cell are grouped properly but I dont see the dots.
In order to see the dots, I need to remove the groupCells property.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: this [code](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/XKZXyv) works inside the same page.

Thanks

Comment: can you, please, add a code snippet with the issue (one working with dots and other working with groupcells) in order to we can test some quick annoying repair jobs to find a solution?
Thanks! =)

Comment: Here are all options: http://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html

Comment: Have you tried adding "groupCells": true ?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code (at least some example that demonstrates the problem) it's really hard to help, however here is an example with what you need:

```js
$('.carousel').flickity({
  contain: true,
  groupCells: 4
});
```

```css
/* external css: flickity.css */

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: #EEE;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 28%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}

.carousel-cell.is-selected {
  background: #ED2;
}

/* cell number */
.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(carousel-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0/dist/flickity.css" media="screen">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2.0/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<h1>Flickity - groupCells</h1>
<div class="carousel" id="mycarousel" data-flickity='{"groupCells": 4 }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but as I said before if I put the sample code inside my page it works as expected. The problem comes with the case where I am using an angularjs custom directive, I added some code above

Comment: The specific problem in your page can be wrong positioning of other elements or css that caused the dots to be hidden. Without looking at your page it's really hard to help and understand the problem.

Comment: the page is created dinamically adding a custom directive, do you want me to post all the html template of my directive?

Comment: Will be much better if you can create a jsfiddle with all the html/css/js to look at :)

Comment: is it possible having angularjs and more than 1 js class?

Comment: in jsfiddle,  
is it possible having angularjs and more than 1 js class at the same time?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand the meaning of "js class". what exactly is js class?